# Inability to install on Acer 4530 with Vista

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

I have tried to make a clean Ubuntu 12.04 installation on an Acer 4530 currently running Win Vista. It appears that even though I am able to switch booting sources through the BIOS, these other sources, USB ports and DVD drive are not active and they can not be activated through the BIOS. I really would love to format and have a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04 but nothing works. WUBI does not work since it requires reboot through USB port, DVD does not work with an error message saying no operating system found. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi doesn't "*require reboot through USB port*". But why are you trying to use Wubi? If you want to format and do a clean install, Wubi is not the right method.

You're do best to figure out why you DVD won't boot? Have you tried it on another machine? It's probably just a bad burn. Make sure you [verify the `md5sum`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the ISO prior to burning and burn at the slowest speed.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and trying very hard to get away from Win. I use a Win7 system to do all of my downloading and preparation and keeping the target Vista system clean. I have burned 3 different DVDs, all verified. The ISO file which I download appears as a zip file in my Win7 environment. I have tried both ways, unzip and then burn and burn the straight zip/iso file. The DVD is working fine in that it does its job and it is now active as a boot in my BIOS. It looks to me I am doing something wrong either in my download or in the preparation of the DVD. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Tony You have some archive tool (Winzip, WinRar etc.) that's making the ISO appear like a ZIP file. It's not. Extracting the contents and burning to DVD will not work. If you have [burned the DVD correctly](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), then you will be able to boot from it via a BIOS override or setting the BIOS boot order to first check the DVD.